# How can I make a custom authentication or authorize attribute in asp.netcore 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

So I want to make an authentication attribute that I can put on my methods. Example

```
[Attribute]
    public void getUsers()
    {

    }
```

I want the attribute to have some logic in it, so I can verify the information coming in, to see if the user is allowed to access that method.
I have done a lot of searching and a lot of them use .Net or mvc and I want .netcore. Any help is welcome

Comment: Possible duplicate of (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464359/how-do-you-create-a-custom-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: What do you mean by **if the user is allowed to access that method**? You could try `IAuthorizationFilter` to check `User Claims`, you could place your logic in `IAuthorizationFilter`. What is the issue to use with the suggestion from Ryan.